# How to use @Scheduled(cron) with SpEL in spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, cron

I have a method that I want spring to schedule - for that matter I'm using the `@Scheduled` annotation - and to be more exact, I'm using a cron expression.
My cron expression is in a property file that is called scheduler.properties.
When I'm using it as a placeholder `@Scheduled(cron="${cron}")` - everything works great; but I want to use SpEL ( `@Scheduled(cron="#{scheduler['cron']}")` ) , and it does't work - throws the following exception:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in #{scheduler['cron']})`

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
Here is my cron expression from the properties file: `cron=0 0/1 * * * ?`

Here is the stack trace that I get:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in #{scheduler['cron']})
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.parse(CronSequenceGenerator.java:233)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.<init>(CronSequenceGenerator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:44)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:188)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:209)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

**SECOND EDIT:**
It seems that spring is trying to parse the following string as the cron experssion "#{scheduler['cron']}" insraed of the actual cron expression itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, the value of the cron expression in your properties file is incorrect.

It does not conform to the expected syntax.

The value should contain six fields and look something like this.

```
* 10 * * * *
```

Here's the code that throws this exception

```
/**
 * Parse the given pattern expression.
 */
private void parse(String expression) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    String[] fields = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(expression, " ");
    if (fields.length != 6) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(""
                + "cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found %d in %s)", fields.length, expression));
    }
```

It may not be possible to externalize cron configuration using spEL in an Annotation.

The alternatives are to use XML or use the cron expression.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?91203-Scheduled-and-externalization-of-configuration-for-fixedDelay-and-fixedRate-problem

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply - but my cron expression is correct, as I said, it works when I'm using this it as a placeholder. My expresseion is `cron=0 0/1 * * * ?`

Comment: Hi Noam, Good information. I agree that that value looks correct. You may have uncovered a defect in the code that is reporting the bug. Especially as it works in the annotation. I would try enclosing the cron string in single or double quotes as a "see if it sticks" strategy. Share the stack trace with us and then we can lookup the Spring source to see what that code is doing and that should help us get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Hi Rob, I've published the stack trace; and I even tried the single and double quotes - as you suggested - but I still get the same exception... 
Just for debuging, I've added a member to this class and annotated it like this:
`@Value("#{scheduler['cron']}")` - it's value was the cron expression - 0 0/1 * * * ?

Comment: I'm loading up the spring-framework project and will have a look at the code to see what is happening.

Comment: It's clear now from the spring-framework code attached that the expression it is trying to parse is "#{scheduler['cron']}" which is not as we expect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10731/discussion-between-noam-and-rob)

Answer (score 1):

Always specify like this in property file: Notice the space in between frequency.

## run refresh job every day a 9am

job.cron.rate=0 0 9 * * *

Example patterns:

```
* "0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
* "*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
* "0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
* "0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 and 10 o'clock every day.
* "0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
* "0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
```

Use it like this in Code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron.rate}")    
public void perform() throws InterruptedException {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by reading property file with context:property-placeholder

`<util:properties id="applicationProps" location="/WEB-INF/classes/properties/application.properties" />
**<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="applicationProps"  />**`

Hope it helps someone!!

Answer (score 0):

It works. I spent days figuring out... but this indeed works.

1. You should set environment variable like you do for JAVA_HOME etc.
2. Close your IDE.

---

```
export cron_scheduler_expression="0 19 21 * * *"
```

Then restart your IDE, Eclipse or NetBeans whatever you are using.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron_scheduler_expression}")
public void runSchedulerTask(){

}
```